# Issue with d3.js bar graph

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, bar-chart

I am porting a bar graph using json data and d3.js
But I am not able to do so. I have tried many ways.
Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
fill: none;
stroke: #000;
shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
fill: steelblue;
}

.x.axis path {
 display: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>



var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
.rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
.rangeRound([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
.range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left")
.tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = [
        {
        "State": "AL",
        "Under 5 Years": 310504,
        "5 to 13 Years": 552339,
        "14 to 17 Years": 259034
        },
        {
        "State": "PA",
        "Under 5 Years": 737462,
        "5 to 13 Years": 1345341,
        "14 to 17 Years": 679201
        },
        {
        "State": "RI",
        "Under 5 Years": 60934,
        "5 to 13 Years": 111408,
        "14 to 17 Years": 56198
        },
        {
        "State": "SC",
        "Under 5 Years": 303024,
        "5 to 13 Years": 517803,
        "14 to 17 Years": 245400
        },
        {
        "State": "SD",
        "Under 5 Years": 58566,
        "5 to 13 Years": 94438,
        "14 to 17 Years": 45305
        },
        {
        "State": "TN",
        "Under 5 Years": 416334,
        "5 to 13 Years": 725948,
        "14 to 17 Years": 336312
        },
        {
        "State": "TX",
        "Under 5 Years": 2027307,
        "5 to 13 Years": 3277946,
        "14 to 17 Years": 1420518
        },
        {
        "State": "WY",
        "Under 5 Years": 38253,
        "5 to 13 Years": 60890,
        "14 to 17 Years": 29314
        }
    ];

d3.json.parse(data, function(error, data) {
color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "State"; }));

data.forEach(function(d) {
var y0 = 0;
d.ages = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
d.total = d.ages[d.ages.length - 1].y1;
});


x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.State; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]);

 svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

 svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
 .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Population");

 var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
  .data(data)
 .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.State) + ",0)"; });

 state.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
 .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

 var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(color.domain().slice().reverse())
 .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width - 24)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text(function(d) { return d; });

 });

 </script>
```

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no d3.json.parse method.  If you get rid of that everything seems to work and here's a [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/rwZkU/) with it.

Answer (score 0):

This may help,

1. Take your data and stick it in an external json file.

   For example, "mydata.json"
2. Instead of

   ```
   d3.json.parse(data, function(error, data)
   ```
3. Remove parse and replace your data with the path to your external json file.

   ```
    d3.json(path/mydata.json, function(error, data)
   ```
4. Make sure the external file is in the correct json format